# how to resize images in python 3.2

Tags: python, image

I googled about resizing images in python. but I found nothing helpful in python 3.2.

is there any solution to my problem?

I do not need any complicated image processing but just a resizing function run on python 3.2.

please give me some advises.

Thanks you.

Comment: https://github.com/sloonz/pil-py3k/tree/a75c372ed17b3d06c0d58c1db03c9215da9c4bbb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [Python Imaging Library (PIL)](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/).

```
out = im.resize((128, 128))
```

See example "Geometrical Transforms"
http://effbot.org/imagingbook/introduction.htm

Comment: but PIL does not support python 3.2. is there any other alternatives?

Comment: @Web Engineer: have you noticed the comment of Varela? It seems that it is available for Python 3 too (says "port to py3k"); haven't tried yet though.

Answer (score 4):

[Pillow](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow) is a fork of PIL, except it's updated and supports Python 3x. You should consider using Pillow, since its interface is very similar to PIL. E.g. the [syntax for geometrical transformations](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/handbook/tutorial.html#geometrical-transforms) [resizes] are the same:

```py
im = Image.open("foo.png")
out = im.resize((128, 128))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try the [unofficial packages](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/).

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I resize images in my python .. Let's say I'm importing a picture call logo.png

```
from tkinter import PhotoImage

Img = PhotoImage(file = "logo. Png").resample(10, 10)
```

The "resample" will resize it to "10, 10"  pls tell me if I'm correct

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Note that you can format your code by indenting it with four spaces.